# Proving a nilpotent matrix has only 0 as eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like a verification of this proof:

*Prove that $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a nilpotent matrix if and only if $0$ is its only eigenvalue.*

---

($\Rightarrow$): if $A$ is nilpotent, then there's a index $k \le n$ such that $A^k = 0$. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Since $Ax = \lambda x$, $A^kx = \lambda^k x = 0$, so $\lambda^k x = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda = 0$.

($\Leftarrow$): argue for the sake of contradition that $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$ but $A$ is not nilpotent. Then $A \ne 0, A^2 \ne 0, \dots, A^n \ne 0$. Since $Ax = \lambda x$ with $x \ne 0$, $Ax = 0, A^2x = 0, \dots, A^nx = 0$. A contradition.

But something feels off about this, I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Use triangular form or Jordan form.

Comment: You can clarify your thoughts by being more explicit about what $x$ is. Before you use the symbol $x$, make sure to introduce it with a quantifier, like "there exists $x$ such that", or "there exists $x\neq0$ such that", or "for all $x$ we have", or similarly.

Comment: @fredgoodman, got it. In the second proof, put $A$ into jordan form and therefore conclude $A$'s jordan form has $0$ along its diagonal and $1$s or $0$s along the super diagonal, which is a nilpotent matrix. Therefore A is similar to a nilpotent matrix.

Comment: I'm reluctant to accept that target as a duplicate.  The main reason is that this Question is about "if and only if" (and perhaps about proof verification, but that's a minor aspect if the proof provided is the standard one).  A minor aspect is that the target proposed includes a statement that the result is already know for *matrices* and wants some clarification about *operators* (although the proof is essentially the same idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A^k = 0$ and $A v= \lambda v$ then $\lambda^k = 0$ and so $\lambda = 0$.

If all eigenvalues are zero, then the characteristic polynomial is $x^n$ and so Cayley Hamilton gives $A^n = 0$ hence $A$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 0):

An $n$-by-$n$ matrix has a minimal polynomial $m(X)$: this means that
$f(A)=0$ for a complex polynomial if and only if $m\mid f$. Then $f$ is nilpotent if $m(X)=X^k$ for some $k$. Otherwise $m(X)=(X-\lambda)g(X)$
for some nonzero $\lambda$. Then $g(A)\ne0$. Any vector in the image
of $g(A)$ will be an eigenvector of $A$ for $\lambda$.